# How to scroll scrollView so that TextField move above Keyboard in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have setup a UI in which there are 6 fields in the `ScrollView` as the following:

```
...
         ScrollView {

                IndicatorTextField(
                    index: 0,
                    hint: "Full Name",
                    icon: .imageUserBlue,
                    activeFieldTag: self.$activeFieldTag,
                    type: .alphabet
                ).padding(.top, 48)

                IndicatorTextField(
                    index: 1,
                    hint: "Email Address",
                    icon: .imageEmail,
                    activeFieldTag: self.$activeFieldTag,
                    type: .emailAddress
                ).padding(.top, 8)

                IndicatorTextField(
                    index: 2,
                    hint: "Home Town",
                    icon: .imageLocation,
                    activeFieldTag: self.$activeFieldTag,
                    type: .alphabet
                ).padding(.top, 8)

                IndicatorTextField(
                    index: 3,
                    hint: "Password",
                    icon: .imageLock,
                    activeFieldTag: self.$activeFieldTag,
                    indicatorColor: .reddishPink
                ).padding(.top, 8)

                IndicatorTextField(
                    index: 4,
                    hint: "Date of Birth",
                    icon: .imageCalender,
                    activeFieldTag: self.$activeFieldTag,
                    type: .numbersAndPunctuation,
                    indicatorColor: .reddishPink
                ).padding(.top, 8)

                IndicatorTextField(
                    index: 5,
                    hint: "Gender",
                    icon: .imageUserRed,
                    activeFieldTag: self.$activeFieldTag,
                    indicatorColor: .reddishPink,
                    returnKey: .default
                ).padding(.top, 8)

                Spacer()
                    .frame(width: 0, height: -keyboardObserver.lastViewAdjustment)
            }
            .background(GeometryGetter(rect: $keyboardObserver.lastViewRect))
...
```

Here is [keyboardObserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59992130/how-to-add-animation-on-spacer-height-changes-in-scrollview-in-swiftui)

When the keyboard appears then I just change the `Spacer` height enough to scroll till last field.

Now, I want to auto scroll the firstResponder above the Keyboard.

Does anyone know about how to scroll `ScrollView` with **SwiftUI** code?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to scroll `ScrollView` in SwiftUI so far, but I used a workaround, where I tell the parent scroll view to scroll from a wrapper for `UITextField`: https://lostmoa.com/blog/ScrollTextFieldIntoVisibleRange/

I found it's an easier solution than wrapping `UIScrollView`.